# mapStateToProps doesn't map to props for some reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm fairly new to React/Redux. The redux Chrome devtools tell me that I'm successfully creating and modifying state.  However, while the console log 'dah state' runs and satisfactorily tells me that my state has the correct information in it, I'm not mapping to props at that point.

I'm not entirely sure if my reducer is made correctly, but I suspect that it is because I'm creating new state, even though it doesn't map to props.

I'm also fairly sure that mapStateToProps, while it runs, is not triggering a rerender

**Here is my relevant container**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import TopicsGrid from '../components/TopicsGrid.jsx';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { fetchTopics } from '../actions/topics';
    import Main from '../components/Main.jsx';

    class AboutContainer extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                topics: [{
                    title: '',
                    description: '',
                    link: '',
                    src: '',
                    message: '',
                    selected: false,
                    _id: ''
                }]
            }
        }
        onChange = (action) => {
            this.props.dispatch(action);
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            fetchTopics();
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            console.log('nextProps', nextProps)
            this.setState({
                topics: nextProps.topics
            })
        }
        render() {
            console.log('PROPS', this.props)
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <TopicsGrid 
                    topics={this.state.topics} 
                    onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    AboutContainer.propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        topics: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    AboutContainer.defaultProps = {
        state: {
            topics: [{
                    title: '',
                    description: '',
                    link: '',
                    src: '',
                    message: '',
                    selected: false,
                    _id: ''
                }]
        }
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            dispatch: dispatch
        }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        console.log('dah state', state)
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            topics: state.topics.topics
        })
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AboutContainer);
```

**Here is my reducer**

```
import * as types from '../constants/action-types';
import * as SectionNames from '../constants/section-names';

const initialState = {
    topics: []
}

export default function about(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.section !== SectionNames.TOPICS) {
        return state;
    }

    let mods = {};
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.FETCH_TOPICS_SUCCESS:
            mods = {
                    topics: action.topics
                }
                // return Object.assign({}, state, {
                // topics: action.topics
                // });
            break;

        case types.FETCH_TOPICS_ERROR:
            mods = {
                    topics: action.topics
                }
                // return Object.assign({}, state, {
                //     topics: action.topics
                // });
            break;

        case types.TOPIC_SELECTED:
            console.log('selected')
            //topic can be selected or unselected
            //only one topic can be selected at once.
            mods = {
                    topics: action.topics
                }
            mods.topics[action.index].selected = true;
            return Object.assign({}, state, mods);
            break;

        case types.TOPIC_UNSELECTED:
            //topic can be selected or unselected
            //only one topic can be selected at once.
            mods = {
                    topics: action.topics
                }
            mods.topics[action.index].selected = false
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }

    return Object.assign({}, state, mods);

}
```

Comment: you should just map the parts of the state that component uses, otherwise a shallow prop check in shouldComponentUpdate will return true more often than it needs, thus making your app less efficient. Extend from React.PureComponent instead and the shallow check will already be there for you. Also avoid assigning props to component state if you can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using mapStateToProps you can use props directly instead of passing them into the component state.

```
render() {
    const { topics } = this.props
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <TopicsGrid 
                topics={topics}
                onChange={this.onChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@connect(state => ({
    data: state.module.data
  }), {actoionCreators});
```

use this at the top of your class it will decorate your class and map states to props

in your module you have to switch on action.type, in each case you should return an object with your custom changes in state for example in LOAD_SUCCESS you have to return an object like this :

```
return {
...state,
loading:false,
loaded:true,
data:action.data
  }
```

so redux knows that when loadSuccess dispatched the state is gonna change with loading to false and ....

notice that reduce should return state when an unknown action dispathed so in your default case you should return state